# How to remove the background of an image based on the design around the region of interest?

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, mobile

I am creating an application that allows the user to select a region of interest from wound images. As soon as the region of interest was selected by drawing on the screen, the algorithm will segment and remove the background from the image, leaving it with a black background and highlighting only that area of ​​the wound. I am still in the initial phase of the application, today it is only drawing the region of interest, I would like help to be able to carry out this segmentation in the best possible way and that it would serve for several images of wounds, whether large, small, light, dark, etc.
I need to segment the image so that I can later run an algorithm that will classify the wound tissues. That's why I need this segmentation.

I'm using the lib Canvas of the android itself to make the drawing.
How to use the watershed and how can I do from what I have?

application screen:

[image]

In the image, the green design around the wound will be the reference for the segmentation algorithm.

Example of output:

[image]

Comment: If the users is drawing the area on screen, why do you need some special algorithm for that at all?
The user gives you the exact area he wants to see

Comment: I need to segment the image so that I can later run an algorithm that will classify the wound tissues. That's why I need this segmentation. If you can help me, I thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are working with Java and Kotlin in Android so I have no idea how to work with them in OpenCV, but I can give you an example of how I would do it in python, and hopefully, you can convert it to Java.

Create a black image (i.e. image having all zeros) of the same dimensions of the input image which should be the screen in your case. This can be done by `mask = np.zeros((img.shape), dtype=np.uint8)` where img is the image. Now when the user draws the boundary of the wound on the screen draw it on the blank mask as well. Find contours using `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` mode. The syntax in python would be:

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

After this, you will be having one contour which we will fill to obtain our mask.

```
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

With the mask made use bitwise and to extract your ROI.

```
roi = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

This should do it provided you can convert it to Java or Kotlin.